# How to keep components pure when defining functions in smart containers?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I use react, redux and immutablejs in my app. The store is immutable, and  is mapped to the props. When mapping the dispatch to props, I provide helper functions. The helper functions are comparable with this piece of code in the redux TodoList example:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onTodoClick: (id) => {
      dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I currently have is that my pure components render too often: the connect above creates an `onTodoClick` function every connect.
When the PureRenderMixin shallowCompares the currentProps to the newProps, it marks the component as shouldUpdate because the pointers have changed.

How do I define helper functions in containers while keeping the rendercount of the components low?

I have already looked at reselect but planned to only use it for computing a derived state in the mapStateToProps. Is it better to just create a selector for every connect you do, so your functions are memoized as well?

Comment: Have a look at [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate). You might be able to adjust the component to not render as often.

Comment: @MarioTacke that's exactly what the `pureRenderMixin` already does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a hack, but you could just memoize that function based on the `dispatch` parameter (assuming redux always send the same function for the same store):

```
let lastDispatch;
let dispatchProps;
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  if (!dispatchProps || dispatch !== lastDispatch) {
    dispatchProps = {
      onTodoClick: (id) => {
        dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
      }
    }
    lastDispatch = dispatch;
  }
  return dispatchProps;
}
```

or using lodash memoize:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = _.memoize((dispatch) => {
  return {
    onTodoClick: (id) => {
      dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
    }
  }
})
```

UPDATE: that's not a hack, it seems to be aligned with their official docs:

> Note: in advanced scenarios where you need more control over the rendering performance, mapDispatchToProps() can also return a function. In this case, that function will be used as mapDispatchToProps() for a particular component instance. This allows you to do per-instance memoization. You can refer to #279 and the tests it adds for more details. Most apps never need this.

See: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options

Answer (score 0):

Throttle function in lodash may solve your problem. It will ensure that components are rendered at most once every x miliseconds.